# Нужна ли запятая при причастном обороте?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

Нужно ли поставить здесь запятые (в скобках)?

**Пользователи с должностью младшего модератора и выше оставляют за собой право отклониться от рамок(,) предлагаемых в этом разделе мер наказаний(,) и самостоятельно определить меры наказания в каждом конкретном случае, если это не противоречит Правилам Сервисов.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Главное предложение:

Пользователи оставляют право отклониться и определить меры наказания.

*...отклониться (от чего?) от рамок (каких?), **предлагаемых в этом разделе мер наказаний**, и определить...* - причастный оборот обособлен двумя запятыми.

Прописные у *Правилам Сервисов* на совести администрации: они здесь не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно ли поставить здесь запятые (в скобках)?
>
> *Пользователи с должностью младшего модератора и выше оставляют за собой право отклониться от рамок(,) предлагаемых в этом разделе мер наказаний(,) и самостоятельно определить…*

**НЕ НУЖНО.**

Основное сообщение запятых не требует:

*Пользователи с должностью младшего модератора и выше оставляют за собой право отклониться от рамок **мер наказаний** и самостоятельно определить…*

*Мер (наказаний)* (каких?) — ***предлагаемых в этом разделе*** (определительный оборот, выраженный причастием  с зависимыми словами).

**Определительный оборот, находящийся ПЕРЕД определяемым словом, обособления не требует**.

См. ПАС:

> **§ 46…**
>
> 2. Определительный оборот, стоящий перед определяемым существительным, **не отделяется** запятой от определяемого слова: *Тишина этой ночи была наполнена музыкой **еще не родившегося Чайковского*** (Зал.); *В этой шкатулке Языков потом хранил свои сувениры из Тригорского, письма к нему Пушкина и Осиповых-Вульф и **подаренный ему Пушкиным** автограф стихов «Улукоморья дуб зеленый...»* (Гейч.); ***Полные мрака** леса стояли недвижно.*

Запятыми этот оборот выделялся бы в положении **после** определяемого существительного:

*Пользователи с должностью младшего модератора и выше оставляют за собой право отклониться от рамок мер наказаний, **предлагаемых в этом разделе**, и самостоятельно определить…*

**P. S.**

Если же считать, что определительный оборот относится к существительному ***рамок***, то пунктуация должна была бы быть такой:

*Пользователи с должностью младшего модератора и выше оставляют за собой право отклониться от рамок, **предлагаемых в этом разделе**, мер наказаний и самостоятельно определить…*

**Но такой ли смысл вкладывал в этот текст его составитель?..**

Answer (score 0):

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ к принятому ответу**

Я тоже выбираю вариант **с обособлением:**

*Пользователи с должностью младшего модератора и выше оставляют за собой право отклониться от **РАМОК**, (каких?) **предлагаемых в этом разделе мер наказаний,**  и самостоятельно определить **меры наказания** в каждом конкретном случае, если это не противоречит Правилам Сервисов.*

**Пояснение**

Итак, спорный вопрос: к чему относится оборот,  **к рамкам или к наказаниям?** Думается, что все же **к рамкам**, а иначе говоря, к степенным рамкам мер наказаний.

**[Из словаря](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/brokgauz_efron/135369/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)**

**МЕРА НАКАЗАНИЯ**

**Размер наказания**, избранный судом в определенных законом для данного преступного деяния пределах (при **лестничной системе** — см. [Лестница наказаний](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/brokgauz_efron/60891/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) — в пределах **степени**).

**А рамки — это что?**  Вероятно, они соответствуют **лестнице наказаний,** и  можно сказать, что существуют  **степенные рамки** мер наказаний.  И тогда предлагаются именно  эти **рамки**, а не наказания.

**P. S.**  Мой голос за автора вопроса и за автора ответа.